# SQL IF / ELSE Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, if-statement

I have a Select statement, where I need to add a IF/ELSE Statement so that,

```
IF @P_COUNT = 'X' 
    show the Count(*) FROM SELECT statement 
ELSE 
    I need to return table from the SELECT statement results
```

Currently this is what I have but its NOT working properly.

```
@P_COUNT            VARCHAR(1)

IF @P_COUNT = 'X' 
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    ELSE SELECT * FROM (
   (SELECT ... UNION ... ) AS A
    LEFT JOIN 
   (SELECT A, B, C, D FROM Table_1) AS B
    ON WHERE A.XX = B.XX
    LEFT JOIN 
   (SELECT A, B, C, D FROM Table_1) AS C
    ) AS D
```

Current results :

```
IF @P_COUNT = 'X', RESULT => 1 Expected => 26017
IF @P_COUNT = '', RESULT => returns proper Select statement.
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: I don't see what your second code block has to do with your first.  How many tables are you dealing with?

Comment: Could you show the calling code? You can't create a function that returns a scalar value in some cases and a table in other cases. You'd have to use two different functions.

Comment: This looks like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: The answer provided by Gordon worked...  I am pretty new to SQL and the syntax was confusing.  Gordon's explanation of having 2 separate Select Queries each needing its own FROM clause worked. I was to use single From clause to get results back....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
IF @P_COUNT = 'X' 
BEGIN
   SELECT COUNT(*) 
   FROM (
   (SELECT ... UNION ... ) AS A
    LEFT JOIN 
   (SELECT A, B, C, D FROM Table_1) AS B
    ON WHERE A.XX = B.XX
    LEFT JOIN 
   (SELECT A, B, C, D FROM Table_1) AS C
    ) AS D 
END
ELSE
BEGIN
   SELECT * FROM (
   (SELECT ... UNION ... ) AS A
    LEFT JOIN 
   (SELECT A, B, C, D FROM Table_1) AS B
    ON WHERE A.XX = B.XX
    LEFT JOIN 
   (SELECT A, B, C, D FROM Table_1) AS C
    ) AS D 
END;
```

You have two separate `SELECT` queries.  They each need a `FROM` clause.